# In Toad in an Oracle DB running a script returns a date and running a query includes time

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, toad

First time poster, long time benefiter of others' posts!

I use Toad to interact with an Oracle database at work.

I'm working on a PL/SQL Script that pulls some data (several Select statements that conditionally fork depending on what they find).

There is a particular column in a table I use that has the data type of 'DATE'.

Names of things have been changed to protect the innocent...

If I run the following:

```
SELECT date FROM my_table;
```

...as a query I get a full time stamp with the date AND time.

If I run it as a script it only returns the date (M/DD/YYYY).

I confirmed this by opening a new editor tab that only had this statement in it to ensure it wasn't something else in my code.

I can't figure out why the query would return time although I'm glad it does. In that case why does the script execution only return a date?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If running it as a script, your script output will show the date in whatever your default nls_date_format is.  You can change it on the fly for the session:

Try running as a script:

```
alter session set nls_date_format = 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS';
select sysdate from dual;
```